# How to create a new ActiveModel::Error with message for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test the `save` functionality of my code which uses forms. Following is my code:

> **controller.rb**

```rb
def create
  @project = Project.new(params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :team_id, :hackathon_id))

  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = I18n.t('controllers.hackathons.hackathon_registered')
    redirect_to projects_path
  else
    @errors = form_errors(
      @project.errors,
      %i[name description team_id]
    )
    byebug
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

> **rspec file**

```rb
subject { post :create, params: params }
let(:params) do
  {
    hackathon_id: mock_hackathon.id,
    project: {
      name: 'Hackathon101',
      team_id: mock_team.id,
      hackathon_id: mock_hackathon.id,
      description: 'This is a description'
    }
  }
end

context 'when unsuccessful save' do
  let(:save_value) { false }

  before do
    allow(project).to receive(:errors).and_return(ActiveModel::Errors.new(name: 'name not valid'))
    subject
  end

  it { expect(assigns(:errors)).not_to be_nil }
  it { is_expected.to render_template('signup_teams/new') }
  it { is_expected.to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity) }
end
```

Now here when I am unable to create a new `ActiveModel::Error` with an error message to check the value, the error created here always has an empty value.

Any suggestions would be great..!!

Comment: If your model has validation rules just pass invalid params.

Comment: I'd recommend as Yakov, if there's any validation rule, pass simply invalid params. Though if that's not an option you have to make failing the `Project#save` method (that I assume you did) and initiate the `ActiveModel::Error` differently. [Here](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveModel/Errors) you can see the first parameter should be a model and then you can add errors by calling `add(:name, 'is not valid')`.

Comment: Thank You @David, I created the error with the model and then added the details for the errors and it worked.